# Problem accessing value from object in array with lodash find

Tags: javascript, lodash

So I have an array like so

```
images = [ { "id":8471226, "base64Image":"encodedText" }, ... ]
```

But when I try to access the encodedText in my code I'm getting undefined

```
let id = 8480948
console.log( _.find(images, { id }) ); // undefined
console.log(id)
console.log(images)
```

```js
const images = [{id: 8471226, base64Image: "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{id: 8477463, base64Image: "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{id: 8479407, base64Image: "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{id: 8477961, base64Image: "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{id: 8470619, base64Image: "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{id: 8471233, base64Image: "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{id: 8471239, base64Image: "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{id: 8472382, base64Image: "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{id: 8473933, base64Image: "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{id: 8475149, base64Image: "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{id: 8475151, base64Image: "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{id: 8475222, base64Image: "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{id: 8475663, base64Image: "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{id: 8475791, base64Image: "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{id: 8476234, base64Image: "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{id: 8476399, base64Image: "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{id: 8476474, base64Image: "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{id: 8476923, base64Image: "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{id: 8477355, base64Image: "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{id: 8477425, base64Image: "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{id: 8477509, base64Image: "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{id: 8477520, base64Image: "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{id: 8478401, base64Image: "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{id: 8479315, base64Image: "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{id: 8480002, base64Image: "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{id: 8480948, base64Image: "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"}]
let id = 8480948
console.log( _.find(images, { id }) ); // undefined
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

When I right click the array and store as global variable in chrome dev tools it is working as intended?

Here's an image of the output

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

```
[{"id": 8471226, "base64Image": "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{"id": 8477463, "base64Image": "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{"id": 8479407, "base64Image": "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{"id": 8477961, "base64Image": "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{"id": 8470619, "base64Image": "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{"id": 8471233, "base64Image": "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{"id": 8471239, "base64Image": "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{"id": 8472382, "base64Image": "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{"id": 8473933, "base64Image": "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{"id": 8475149, "base64Image": "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{"id": 8475151, "base64Image": "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{"id": 8475222, "base64Image": "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{"id": 8475663, "base64Image": "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{"id": 8475791, "base64Image": "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{"id": 8476234, "base64Image": "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{"id": 8476399, "base64Image": "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{"id": 8476474, "base64Image": "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{"id": 8476923, "base64Image": "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{"id": 8477355, "base64Image": "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{"id": 8477425, "base64Image": "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{"id": 8477509, "base64Image": "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{"id": 8477520, "base64Image": "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{"id": 8478401, "base64Image": "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{"id": 8479315, "base64Image": "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{"id": 8480002, "base64Image": "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"},
{"id": 8480948, "base64Image": "KAAAAGgAAAAAAAAwvnlmsC+LHdzl+WxWjRcE1u4G8K"}]
```

Comment: There's no `id` of `8480948` in the `images` text nor in your image of code. If you fix that, I can't reproduce the problem

Comment: I've included the rest of the array!

Comment: Arrays should have *values* only, not key-value pairs like `0: { ... }` - best to fix your syntax

Comment: Fixed - was formatted from copying chrome output

Comment: Thanks, but still can't reproduce - see snippet

Comment: Is your array populated asynchronously? This would explain why you're seeing different values at different times (unless I'm misinterpreting the problem)

Comment: Ya you're right the problem ended up being my array was created asynchronously and chrome console logs it at a different point in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is the actual problem in your code. But this seems to be working for me. I've used array.find method. More info about Array.find is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            var images = [{ "id":8471226, "base64Image":"encodedText" },{"id":234,"base64Image":"somethingelse"}];
            
            console.log("Finding image of id 23:",findImage(234));

            console.log("Finding image of id 8471226:",findImage(8471226));
            
            function findImage(id){
                var found = images.find(function(element) {
                    return element.id == id;
                });
                return found;
            }

            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax seems like 100% correct ES6.

It appears that the record you wish to find in your array simply does not exist.

Notice the IDs in your example differ:

```
8480948
8471226
```

Comment: My mistake I'm looping over a bunch of ids and the image is from a previous one. I've included the rest of the array, which includes the id.

Comment: Here's a fiddle to show that your code does indeed work: https://jsfiddle.net/k86Loa14/1/